# Issue with depencies while running maven build, how can I fix it?

Tags: java, maven, jive

I am trying to build Java project with Maven, but got stuck with this error. I've tried `mvn -U clean install`, tried getting repository folder from my colleagues, but nothing helps.

Here is the error message. It seems that there is no needed dependency but since it is not a direct dependency - I don't know how to fix it.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project-name: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.company-name.jive:project-name:jar:9.0.7.1: Failed to collect dependencies at com.jivesoftware:jive-core:jar:9.0.7.1_1276_18c97f6 -> com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:jar:1.1 -> com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-android-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-android-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:24.0-android-20170926.205728-110 in mygrid (http://repository.mygrid.org.uk/artifactory/remote-repos) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project project-name: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.company-name.jive:project-name:jar:9.0.7.1: Failed to collect dependencies at com.jivesoftware:jive-core:jar:9.0.7.1_1276_18c97f6 -> com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:jar:1.1 -> com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-android-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.company-name.jive:project-name:jar:9.0.7.1: Failed to collect dependencies at com.jivesoftware:jive-core:jar:9.0.7.1_1276_18c97f6 -> com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:jar:1.1 -> com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-android-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    ...
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.jivesoftware:jive-core:jar:9.0.7.1_1276_18c97f6 -> com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:jar:1.1 -> com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-android-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    ...
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-android-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor (DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:541)
    ...
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:24.0-android-20170926.205728-110 in mygrid (http://repository.mygrid.org.uk/artifactory/remote-repos)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1070)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:24.0-android-20170926.205728-110 in mygrid (http://repository.mygrid.org.uk/artifactory/remote-repos)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel (DefaultModelResolver.java:172)
    ...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.mycompany.jive</groupId>
    <artifactId>ru-mycompany-core</artifactId>
    <name>ru-mycompany-core</name>
    <version>${build.version}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.jivesoftware.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>jive-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.7.1-0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <final.name>${project.artifactId}-${build.version}</final.name>
        <build.assembly.format>jar</build.assembly.format>
        <build.version>9.0.7.1</build.version>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>mycompany-artifactory-central</id>
            <url>https://repo.mycompany.ru/artifactory/jive-release</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>google-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>${final.name}</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Unpackages this Jive plugin. Used in conjunction with the -DpluginDirs= property -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jivesoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>jive-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>${servlet.api.artifactId}</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: As the error says, it's not able to find the artifact 'com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:24.0-android-20170926.205728-110' in the artifactory. But I'm able to see the artifact here: https://repository.mygrid.org.uk/artifactory/remote-repos/com/google/guava/guava-parent/24.0-android/. May be you're looking for a specific build of the artifact? Can you post your pom.xml or a snippet of it which contains the dependency?

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I've added my pom.xml.

Comment: Can you set `releases` `enabled` to `true` in your repository with the id 'google-snapshots' and try out? Also, where is the 'repository.mygrid.org.uk' configured? I don't see that in your pom.xml. Do you have it in your settings.xml?

Comment: Changed releases to true - no effect. Tried to changealso snapshots to false - same result.
here is part of settings.xml:
<repository>
<id>mygrid</id>
<url>http://repository.mygrid.org.uk/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
</repository>

Comment: Looks like it's trying to download a snapshot: com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-android-SNAPSHOT (first line of error). Can you try directly adding the dependency: com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:24.0-android to your pom.xml and trying again? Apparently, only 24.0 has snapshot in the artifactory which also does not contain any pom.xml inside it. I recommend you try with another version say 24.1-andriod explicitly added to your pom.xml

Comment: Also, I'm assuming in settings.xml both snapshot and releases are enabled under the repositories

Comment: I tried adding dependency like this:
`
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava-parent</artifactId>
<version>24.1-jre</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>
`
but it didnt help.
Mb something wrong is with my JDK version?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be 24.1-android? Why 24.1-jre? I don't think this is a JDK version issue.

Comment: I think I've tried the wrong dependency. Sorry. Now I've added: <dependency>
<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
<artifactId>guava-parent</artifactId>
<version>24.0-android</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>
Still no effect=(

Comment: I'm sorry, without the code, it's difficult. May be you'll have to remove repositories one by one to see which repo causes the issue. The repositories are scattered over pom.xml and your settings.xml. Can you make a sample project in Github mimicking the same issue and share it?

Comment: I will try to recreate the issue and share code. Thank you very much! But it is late night here, is it OK if I will do it later? Also SO notifys me that its better to move this conversation to the chat. Is it OK for you? (i think it 'OK' here just in case if someone will need it later)

Comment: Sure, add a comment here once your code is ready in Github. Post that we can move the conversation to Chat.